# Managing secure configuration outside version control with Google App Engine JDK

Tags: security, google-app-engine, configuration

My Google App Engine application includes privileged credentials (like OAuth and cookie signing keys) that I don't want to check in to source control (i.e. Git).

I've considered storing these as system properties or environment variables in the `appengine-web.xml` file, however this file includes a number of other things that I do want to version. Where would be a good place to store "secret" application data so that I can easily exclude it from source control?

Comment: Hi @mustpax, did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do it store the credentials in a secure repository (a file that is only accessibly by a superuser that I can trust) and then have a post-build script. Within source control, I have a dummy password in a properties file and then then post-build script runs after a build and replaces the dummy passwords with the real ones. That way the passwords are not in source control, but show up upon every build. This does depend on an automated build/deployment process, but it is very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Put those things into another file/directory and exclude them with `.gitignore`.

Comment: I already know about `.gitignore`. I want to find out the best practice around this area. Should I store this stuff in an unversioned  Java file? Is there a way to include another file from `appengine-web.xml`?

Comment: I don't know the best practise in this case, but I would go with the file format that suits the data you want to store best. Probably a XML  file you load from your application.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, I recommend the strategy of spring-boot's [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). The idea is a stack of configuration sources with the ones toward top override the ones below.

1. Command-line arguments
2. System properties
3. Environment variables
4. Local configuration files (application.yml or application.properties)
5. Configuration files at the classpath

No. 4 is usually in a hidden folder in the user's home directory, e.g `~/.myapp/application.yml`. Only the user can read that file.

For your question, the non-secret, version-controlled properties are put directly in the source code (No. 5 above). Secrets can be also put in 5 but with dummy values. Real secrets overwrite the dummy values at runtime from 1, 2, 3, or 4.

You can either use spring-boot or write your own code following that same strategy.